# How can I 'convert' a string to a vertex to create a graph in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, graph

So I have this project that consists of created a weighted graph based on user input. The input file consists of a .txt file where the first line contains the names of all the cities, and each subsequent line contains the distance between two cities. I'm doing fine until the part where I need to add the edges of the graph. I created classes for the vertices and edges, so that every edge and vertex is an object from those classes. I created a List to store the vertices:

`public static List<Vertex> vertexList = new ArrayList();`

And then a for loop that adds as many vertices as the user inputs:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) { 
            vertexList.add(new Vertex (cities[i]));
```

Where `cities` is an array that contains the names of the cities in the input file.

The input format for the cities and the distance between them is like: '300-Paris-London'. Which means that there's 300km between Paris and London. So what I'm trying to do to create the edges is something like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < vertexList.size(); j++) {
            if (vertexList.get(j).toString() == arrays.get(j)[1]) {
                vertexList.get(j).addEdge(new Edge(arrays.get(j)[2], Integer.parseInt(arrays.get(j)[0])));
            }
```

Where `arrays` is an ArrayList containing multiple arrays, and those arrays represent every pair of cities and their distance. So in the previous example '300-Paris-London' would be one of those arrays, all of them having length 3.

Basically what I'm trying to do with this for loop is to go through the entire list of vertices, use the String value of every vertex and compare it to every array that contains the pairs of cities, and if the String value of the vertex matches the element at index 1, then add a new edge from said vertex to the vertex that corresponds to the element at index 2 of that array. The thing is that 1. The `toString()` function doesn't seem to give me the real String value of every vertex, but rather an unreadable version of it, and 2. I can't figure out how to convert a String from these arrays and convert it to a 'Vertex' data type, since the arguments for the Edge constructor are `(Vertex to, int weight)` .

How can I convert between String and 'Vertex' datatypes? Or is it not possible? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very complex. I guess that it is a good idea for you to create a Vertex class (which you might have already done) that can parse the string representation using a constructor. If '300-Paris-London' should be an example for this, then this can be solved quite easily e.g. by using the String.split(..) method (e.g. vertexString.split("-")). What might also help you: you could override the method toString() in your Vertex class and create the desired string representation.

Comment: How can I override the method? And should I do that in the Vertex class itself or in my other method?